# Windows 10 repeatedly crashing

Tags: windows-10, bsod

Windows 10 keeps hard crashing randomly. I just walked back to my computer to see it crash before I even touched it.

Previously, it was crashing as soon as I logged in. Then I reinstalled Windows 10, and now I can log in again, but it's still BSODing. Here are the error messages I've seen so far (I've been writing them down), every time it's different:

- BAD_POOL_HEADER
- KMODE_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED
- PFN_LIST_CORRUPT (x4)
- SYSTEM_SERVICE_EXCEPTION

I'm guessing it's a hardware issue, but I don't know how to diagnose it.

Update: Just got 2 new ones:

- IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL
- MEMORY_MANAGEMENT

I'm running mdsched.exe now but it hasn't found anything yet. Will run `chkdsk /R` next.

Comment: Have you changed any hardware recently? If not, is there a lot of dust built up inside your PC?

Comment: No, haven't changed hardware, although my Patriot S4 has been acting up. But that's connected to the network by an Ethernet cable. I tried blowing out the dust already. It's not too bad in there.

Comment: Looks like you have problem with your display adapter or memory, find the support from your PC/Laptop manufacturer, update your BIOS and reinstall your graphic card driver from the manufacturer.

Comment: Does it still BSOD if you boot into safe mode? Looking at the list of bug checks, I'm guessing it might be a driver issue or a RAM issue, but I can't say for certain.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried turning off fast start up? That worked for me. Go to:

Power Option > Choose what the power buttons do > Change Settings that are currently unavailable

Then scroll down to see turn on fast startup and uncheck it.

Comment: Not sure what the problem was, this problem has since stopped occurring. Maybe I had a bad driver that has since been patched? I don't think I changed the hardware or boot settings.